# Is there a "Safe" alternative the Data.String.Utils's 'replace' in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm unable to mark as ["Safe"](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html) code containing, for example

```
import Data.String.Utils (replace)

preproc :: String -> String
preproc s = foldl1 fmap (uncurry replace <$> subs)  s
            where subs = [("1","a"),("2","bb"),("3","z"),("4","mr")("0","xx")]
```

because (apparently) [`Data.String.Utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hS3-0.5.8/docs/Data-String-Utils.html)'s is not "safe".

Is there a safe alternative to `replace`? And why isn't `replace` safe anyway?

Comment: you mean, it's not tagged as "safe" - the function is perfectly safe - you could make a patch and send it to the maintainer, he will probably be happy to include it.

Comment: @Michael: Exactly what it says in the linked docs: `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}` fails with a warning that `Data.String.Utils can't be safely imported! The module isn't safe.`

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius That's what Michael is saying. If it were tagged as safe, this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: We're going in circles (I'm not maligning the function): see the quotes around "safe"? I'm asking exactly that: is there something I can substitute so I don't have to import a package that isn't (currently) *tagged as* safe (while I wait for it to be).

Comment: Note: in the documentation you linked on the top right it says: `Safe Haskell None` so the source code is missing the safe declaration. On your computer you probably have only the compiled version of your package so the compiler has no chance to verify the source code for safety: hence, for your safety, it just assumes the module is not safe for a safe use.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Yes, that answers the final (subsidiary) part of the question: It's not "safe" just because it isn't marked as safe. But the main question stands: what can I do instead in the mean time?

Comment: You can write your own `Trustworthy` `MyStrings` module to re-export the safe functions you use from there.

Comment: @Michael, indeed it appears that the module imports only safe things, except for another `Utils` module which could itself be inferred safe.

Comment: @dfeuer: I just wonder if I can write (or if there exists somewhere) some code that does what `replace` is doing in the example, so I don't have to import a module that isn't passing as "Safe".

Comment: Note: marking a module `TrustWorthy` imposes a substantial maintenance burden--you become responsible for ensuring that the imported functions remain safe when the underlying module is updated, and those who don't trust you need to audit that code themselves. All told, it's far better to get the appropriate annotations pushed upstream.

Comment: You absolutely can. Just click on the link to the source code and copy it. You may have to copy and paste some dependencies as well. Once you've pushed the fix upstream, you can use CPP to fix things up for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: `import Data.Text (replace)` - if you can live with the more restricted type signature?

---

1) The `Data.String.Utils` module is not tagged as *safe*, although it should be.

2) The `Data.String.Utils` module *is* safe. Its wrong to call it "not safe", even if you put quotes around "safe". GHC tells you that the module would be unsafe, because it uses a conservative approach: if it can't prove at compile time that the module is safe, it assumes that it is unsafe. But no matter how loud the compiler complains that the module would be unsafe, it still remains perfectly safe.

3) On the other hand, it would be possible to write a module, export some version of `unsafePerformIO`, and mark it as "Trustworthy". GHC would think that the module can be safely imported. But in fact, the module is inherently unsafe.

**So, what are your options now?**

A) Download the source of the package, and modify the modules that you need, and for which you know that they are safe, to include a "Trustworthy" tag at the beginning: `{-# LANGUAGE Trustworthy #-}`

(You may send a patch to the maintainer, or you may keep it to yourself)

B) You write your own version of `replace` and mark it as safe.

C) Maybe you can use `replace` from `Data.Text`. But that is limited to `Text`, whereas the other `replace` function works on arbitrary lists.

At least on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?) there are no other methods with a `[a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]` signature for your use-case.

Comment: "Its wrong to call it 'not safe'" Yes, that clearly sent people on the wrong track!

Comment: The question is really: How do I write the code above to perform do what replace does (in the context given)? Long term is seems like the right solution (not listed above) is to have the maintainer tag the package is safe.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How come the package isn't tagged as safe? You say it should be safe (because it only uses safe functionality), but AFAIK such packages are normally tagged as "Safe-Inferred", if they are really safe. Why isn't this the case for this module?

Comment: @Kritzefitz - I don't say "it should be safe because it only uses safe functionality"... I say "it *is* safe, because the functions it exposes are all pure, and they don't have any side-effects". A module with just one value `foo = unsafePerformIO $ return (42 :: Int)` is also safe, even though it uses unsafePerformIO - it is not safe-inferred though. "safe" means that the functions are pure and that they don't have side-effects. "being tagged as safe" should mean the same in an ideal world, but in this case it is clearly not the same

Comment: Indeed. MissingH fails to compile with Safe explicitly enabled. Pity that the author didn't mark it as Trustworthy.

Comment: Safety works on the module level, not the package one. Those particular modules could be inferred safe if they just claimed safety.

Comment: @dfeuer Okay, but then it's again unclear why that particular module wasn't Safe-Inferred (I thought Michael's comment about the use of `unsafePerformIO` was supposed to explain it, but maybe it wasn't).

Comment: @Kritzefitz, I think I tracked down the problem. Hackage is lying to us. It claims that `Text.Regex` in `regex-compat` is `safe-inferred`, but in fact that module (which I believe to be safe) uses ones from `regex-posix` that themselves actually use (but do not, as far as I can tell, export) unsafe functions. `Data.String.Utils` imports that regex module, and is therefore not inferred safe. The true solution is to get `regex-posix` and/or `regex-compat` to use the appropriate `Trustworthy` pragmas.